# Python: Two Equations, One Variable Solve

Tags: python, numpy

Help. I am relatively new to Python and struggling with the most basic of functions.

I have two equations that I am trying to set equal to one another in order to solve for a single variable. Sounds simple enough. However, I am unable to find a combination of functions to return an answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated for this newbie.

Problem: Solve for x by setting equations E and F equal to one another. E and F represent the expected value of p*w1 and q*w2 respectively.

```
import cvxpy as cvx
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve
import scipy as sc
from scipy import linalg
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

#Define Variable
x = symbols('x')

#Define Wealth Function:
def u(w):
    return ((w/20000)-1)**3

#Define Parameters
p = np.array([0.931, 1/21, 1/56, 1/292, 1/10720, 1/52835, 1/739688, 1/18492204, 1/258890850])
q = np.array([0.969, 1/37, 1/238, 1/7459, 1/648976, 1/5153633, 1/175223510])
c1 = 1
c2 = 2
a1 = np.array([0, 1, 2, 5, 50, 500, 5000, 1000000, 200000000])
a2 = np.array([0, 4, 7, 100, 10000, 1000000, 200000000])

#Define Outcome
w1 = x - c1 + a1
w2 = x - c2 + a2

#Define Expected Value Function
E = Eq(np.dot(p,u(w1)))
F = Eq(np.dot(q,u(w2)))

print(solve((E,F),(x)))
```

Python only returns "[]".

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `Eq` and replace with `E = np.dot(p,u(w1))` and `F = np.dot(q,u(w2))`. And then solve by `print(solve(E-F, x))`. I get something like `[-3398286.84918693, 1731058.4098883 - 3066517.03142943*I, 1731058.4098883 + 3066517.03142943*I]`

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve
import scipy as sc
from scipy import linalg
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

#Define Variable
x = symbols('x')

#Define Wealth Function:
def u(w):
    return ((w/20000)-1)**3

#Define Parameters
p = np.array([0.931, 1/21, 1/56, 1/292, 1/10720, 1/52835, 1/739688, 1/18492204, 1/258890850])
q = np.array([0.969, 1/37, 1/238, 1/7459, 1/648976, 1/5153633, 1/175223510])
c1 = 1
c2 = 2
a1 = np.array([0, 1, 2, 5, 50, 500, 5000, 1000000, 200000000])
a2 = np.array([0, 4, 7, 100, 10000, 1000000, 200000000])

#Define Outcome
w1 = x - c1 + a1
w2 = x - c2 + a2

#Define Expected Value Function
E = np.dot(p,u(w1))
F = np.dot(q,u(w2))

print(solve(E-F, x))
```

prints

```
[-3398286.84918693, 1731058.4098883 - 3066517.03142943*I, 1731058.4098883 + 3066517.03142943*I]
```